# How do i prove using list induction?

Tags: haskell, discrete-mathematics

i have to show by list induction over xs that :
reverse (xs ++ ys) = (reverse ys) ++ (reverse xs)
for all list xs and ys.

Comment: It's not true. You need to restrict the arguments to finite lists. Can you show what you have for the base case, and indicate where you have problems in the induction?

Comment: I mean, for example `reverse (repeat 0 ++ [1,2,3])` is bottom (a non-terminating computation), but `reverse [1,2,3] ++ reverse (repeat 0)` is `3 : 2 : 1 : _|_` (`_|_` = bottom).

Comment: Your base case is for induction over `ys`. Induction over `xs` is easier than induction over `ys`, since `(++)` is defined by pattern-matching on the first argument.

Comment: Hehe, "apologize for the innocence" is a funny typo :D Let's see if I can help you without doing your homework for you. Needs some time for thinking what to tell you and what to leave for you, though.

Comment: @user1964589 - Should be very easy: First, prove the base case and the cases where one of xs or ys is empty. Then, assume that if the law holds for arbitrary xs and ys, prove that it also holds for (x:xs) and (y:ys), where x and y are arbitrary additional elements.

Comment: `reverse(x:(xs++ys)) = 4->` yes, but you must now rewrite the expression correctly! It is `reverse (xs++ys) ++ [x]` and it shows you that, as expected, a new element at the front of the arguments is moved to the tail ba reverse, as it should be. Now you need to prove only that `reverse(x:xs) ++ reverse(ys)` yields the same resutl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all,

```
reverse (xs ++ ys) ≡ reverse ys ++ reverse xs
```

is not true if `xs` is an infinite or partial<sup>(1)</sup> list and `ys` is a finite nonempty list. Because in that case `xs ++ ys` is also infinite or partial, and in both cases,

```
reverse (xs ++ ys) ≡ ⊥
```

but

```
reverse ys ++ reverse xs ≡ reverse ys ++ ⊥
```

and `reverse ys` is a finite nonempty list, so `reverse ys ++ ⊥` is not `⊥` but a partial list with nonempty initial part.

So let us assume that `xs` is a finite list, i.e. `xs ≡ []` or `xs ≡ x : zs` where `zs` is a finite list.

For the base case, we have

```
reverse ([] ++ ys)
≡ reverse ys         -- by 1.
```

and

```
reverse ys ++ reverse []
≡ reverse ys ++ []   -- by 3.
```

So it remains to show that

```
zs ++ [] ≡ zs
```

for all lists `zs` (that is true even if `ys ≡ ⊥` or `ys` is infinite or partial) to complete the proof of the base case.

You prove that by induction over `zs` (that is simple).

Then you go for the induction step. The first two steps are:

```
reverse ((x:xs) ++ ys)
≡ reverse (x:(xs ++ ys))            -- by 2.
≡ reverse (xs ++ ys) ++ [x]         -- by 4.
```

Then you need

- the induction hypothesis
- the associativity of `(++)` [for a complete proof, that needs to be proved too]
- some of the given rules.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> A partial list is a list of the form

```
zs ++ ⊥
```

where `zs` is a finite list, i.e. it is obtained by "cons"ing a finite number (possibly 0) of elements to `⊥` rather than to `[]`.

Comment: The induction hypothesis is `forall ys: reverse (xs ++ ys) ≡ reverse ys ++ reverse xs`. If you translate it into an induction over the length of `xs`, let `P(k) = (length xs == k) => (reverse (xs ++ ys) ≡ reverse ys ++ reverse xs) for all ys`; the base case is `P(0)`, the induction step is `P(n) => P(n+1)`, and the induction hypothesis is `P(n)`.

Comment: In the induction step, you should prove that `reverse ((x:xs) ++ ys) ≡ reverse ys ++ reverse (x:xs)`. You do that by applying the rules you have (and some other identities) to the left and right hand side, until you made both equal. As induction hypothesis, you can use `reverse (xs ++ ys) ≡ reverse ys ++ reverse xs`.